# How do you write a regular expression that allows the special character DOT?

Tags: java, regex

How do you write a regular expression that allows the character DOT(.) in a user name?

For example:

```
R. Robert
X. A. Pauline
```

Answer (score 5):

Escape the dot with a backslash: `\.`

Comment: We are in the java world here he probably needs to escape the backslash as well "\\."

Comment: @James - that's possibly true, but depends where the String is being specified.  If it's in a Java source then yes, but if it's coming from a config file (or any other non-source location) then it wouldn't.  I wouldn't include that as part of the answer because the it's true that the regex string needs to be `\.`; how you enter that may vary depending on the environment, but IMHO is outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 3):

`[a-zA-Z. ]+` allows letters, dot, and space characters.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    String RE = "[a-zA-Z. ]+";
    String name = args[0];
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(RE);

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(name);
    System.err.println("`" + RE + 
                       (m.matches()?"' matches `":"' does not match `") + 
                       name + "'");
  }
}
```

Running:

```
$ java Test "R. Robert"
`[a-zA-Z., ]+' matches `R. Robert'

$ java Test "R.-Robert"
`[a-zA-Z., ]+' does not match `R.-Robert'
```

Answer (score 2):

to search for a dot in a regex you usually need to escape it as it is a special character.

use `\.` to escape.

You don't need to escape if it is part of a capture group:

`[A-Za-z.]` will search for letters and the '.' character.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear - for starters, regexes don't "allow" or "disallow" anything, they merely match (or don't match) text.  It's the code that invokes the regex that will decide what to do (e.g. is the regex searching for partial matches of invalid characters, or specifying a match for an entire whitelist, etc.?).

Reading between the lines, if you're asking for how to include a literal `.` character in a regex, you need to escape it - which in (almost?) all regex engines means preceding it with a backslash.

For instance, the regex:

```
P\..R
```

means "a capital P, then a period (.), then any character, then a capital R", and would match

```
P.AR
P..R
P.$R
```

but not

```
PEAR
PA.R
P.
P\.AR
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The character . is .

For example if you want to get letters and the dot:

[\w.]+

Comment: "The character . is ." only in a character class as in your example. Normally a `.` has to be escaped.