# In regular expression, how can we match the character "." itself?

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regular expression for DOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862479/regular-expression-for-dot)

Say I have a String:

```
String domain =  "www.example.com";
```

To extract the word "example" I am using the split function in java

```
String[] keys = domain.split(".");
String result = keys[1];
```

Clearly this is wrong because the "." is a wrong regular expression since it matches any character.

What is the escape sequence which matches specifically the character "."?

Though this question does seem trivial but I can't seem to find any quick reference or previous answers. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regular expression for DOT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862479/regular-expression-for-dot). Also, [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122675/how-do-you-write-a-regular-expression-that-allows-the-special-character-dot) and [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674930/java-regex-meta-character-and-ordinary-dot).

Comment: Maybe you want to read some basics: [What absolutely every Programmer should know about regular expressions](http://wp.me/p2pTzU-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the regular expression for any literal string by using Pattern.quote().

Pattern.quote(".")  evaluates to "\\."

In this case it would probably be clearer just to use \\.

Answer (score 7):

By escaping it like as follows

```
\\.
```

Comment: Should we say that in regex, the `.` is escaped as `\.`; but as in Java `\ ` is a special character (to escape, ironically), it needs to be escaped as well - hence `\\.`

Answer (score 4):

Use `\\.`. You need to escape it.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: I was just in the process of editing it.

Comment: I saw only single \ so wrote it, it has been updated

Answer (score 2):

You can escape `.` by prefixing it with `\\`. Hence, use `\\.` Reason is that the literal string `\\` is a single backslash. In regular expressions, the backslash is also an escape character. The regular expression `\\` matches a single backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the `.` character by using `\\.` or using the brackets `[.]`.

Hence your code becomes:

```
String[] keys = domain.split("\\."); // or domain.split("[.]");
String result = keys[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Or you could create a class containing the `dot`, without escaping:**

```
[.]
```